# Displaying first and last lines of Text File?

Tags: java, string, text-files, tokenize, filereader

I have a GUI program that I'm using to navigate a text file. It's nothing too complex, just the ability to browse the file and add new information to it. However I would also like to be able to identify the first line in the text file, as well as the last. Basically if I have a text file that looks like this:

- California, West, 1981, 115, 25.99
- New York, East, 1991, 120, 19.95

I wish to, when a button is pushed saying first - the text California comes up, identifying the first line in the text. But I just want California to display, not the rest of the info on the first line. I wish to do this for the last line to, in the same style.

I'm using the FileReader and FileBuffer with StringTokenizer. Is there a way of just calling the first token of the first line and the first token of the last line? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is the data same in every text file

Comment: There's only one text file, but each line is in the same format. Like above, each line has 5 pieces of information separated by commas. I would like to call just the first info (i.e. California, New York).

Answer (score 3):

to get the first token of line you can do

```
String line = "California, West, 1981, 115, 25.99"
String firstToken = line.split(",")[0]
```

to get the lastline i would iterate the whole file and store it in the List and get the last element , something like:

```
String line ="";
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
          while((line = fileReader.readLine())!= null){
                 list.add(line)
         }
 list.get(0) // first line
 list.get(list.size()-1) // last line
```

Comment: Is there no way to read it from the text file? Because the last line will always change, depending on what gets added to the file.

Comment: Now that I read @harshit's example more closely, it seems it covers every part of the original requirement.  *Did you actually try using the code?*

Answer (score 1):

The provided answers should work well in most (the vast majority) of situations.  But for truly enormous input files, it might make sense to take a different approach using a `RandomAccessFile` (RAF).

Using a RAF, read the first bytes until hitting a new line character (for the first line), then seek backwards from the end of the RAF to find the last new line, and read from there until the end (for the last line).

It is even easier if the lines are fixed column width (FCW), but this data is CSV.  For FCW, you can **calculate** where the last line will begin knowing the file size and line width (length), and seek directly to that point.

Comment: I'm just looking to get the first word of the first line though, so far I've only managed to get all of the first line.

Comment: @rjdelight If you have figured how to get the lines required, it might be best to ask another question about tokenizing the line to get the data.  Having said that `String.split(",")[0]` should produce the first part of any line.

Answer (score 1):

This is very old question but right now we have a easy way todo this and I did not found any example of this. I am giving a new answer:
I am using Java 11, but maybe is available in Java 8, have to check.

```
Long lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(file)).count();
String first = Files.lines(Paths.get(file)).findFirst().get();
String last = Files.lines(Paths.get(file)).skip(lines - 1).findFirst().get();
```

Answer (score 0):

A sample how to find out the desired string

Read the file using stream reader

```
  streamreader sr=new streamreader("Your.txt");
  while(sr.peek()>=0)
  {
     string strLine=sr.readLine();
      if(strline.startswith("California"))
      {
         //Dispaly it
       }
          if(strline.startswith("NewYork"))
          {
             //Display it
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there no way to read it from the text file?

If the intervening lines are irrelevant, you can read the first line and scan to the last, without needing to accumulate a collection.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

/** @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614004 */
public class FirstLastTest {

    private static String first, last, line;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
        first = in.readLine();
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line != null) {
                last = line;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(first + "\n" + last);
    }
}
```

Comment: I keep getting an array index out of bounds exception with this for some reason...

Comment: Yes, `args[0]` is a command line parameter for easy testing; in an IDE, just substitute the quoted file name.

Comment: Gotcha, but how would I display only the first word from the first line?